# Login with facebook shows error as unsupported request and failed to login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Login with facebook shows unsupported request and failed to login with unsupported request.

I am using `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.1.0'`

I have added these permissions **["email", "public_profile"]**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about your situation but I came across this error message myself in the last few days after updating my Facebook SDK.

After reading through some documentation I found this page...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews
which talked about web views being deprecated and to ensure that custom tabs were setup correctly, which in turn lead me here...
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/

I found that Facebook SDK 12.1 required that I set androidx.browser:browser to 1.3.0 or higher to function properly with custom tabs.

This required me to then increase my minSdkVersion to 24 which I didn't want to do.

So after a bit more experimenting I found that I could go back to Facebook SDK 8.2, which still functioned fine in my case, and continue using an older version of androidx.browser:browser allowing me to keep the lower minSdkVersion.

Hopefully that helps you too.

Edit:
Just for completeness, what I am currently using in my dependencies is...

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:8.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
```

and to get Facebook login 12.1 working I had to use...

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
```

Comment: My app has the custom tab as mentioned in the page here. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews). So I have updated the SDK alone and checked the Webview is not available. 
 
So we went ahead and added permission in the code as [email and public_profile]. It shows something went wrong error

Comment: Can you confirm this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030638/clarification-regarding-the-custom-tabs-in-version-8-2-0-and-above

Comment: I am not able to test what you are describing in the other question at the moment so can't really comment on it, however while doing my Facebook login update I did find that only updating the Facebook library did swap from launching a web view to launching the browser but the browser wasn't functioning correctly.

So it appeared that I was now using custom tabs but they were broken.
Updating androidx.browser:browser to 1.3.0 is what fixed the broken custom tabs for me with Facebook login 12.1.0.

Facebook login 8.2.0 is working for me with browser 1.0.0 but I don't use email permissions.

Comment: Did you faced a loading of the f logo alone and it not launched the browser, so you have intergrated androidx.browser:browser. Also can u let me know what are the permissions are enabled in the facebook developer and in your code